# Keycloak Deployment on Cloud Run Fails Due to Container Not Starting on Specified Port

Tags: docker-compose, containers, keycloak, google-cloud-run

I am attempting to deploy Keycloak on Google Cloud Run, but I am encountering an error stating that the revision is not ready and cannot serve traffic because the user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Despite setting up the correct port configurations in my Docker Compose and ensuring the container should listen on port 8080, the deployment fails. The error message suggests checking the logs for more details, indicating a problem with the container starting and listening on the specified port.

**What did I do?**
I have set up a Docker Compose file with Keycloak and PostgreSQL services, specifying port 8080 for Keycloak and adjusting the necessary environment variables. I was expecting the Keycloak service to start successfully and listen on port 8080, especially since this configuration works locally. However, when deploying to Cloud Run, I receive an error related to the container not starting on port 8080. I checked the Cloud Run logs as suggested but need further guidance on resolving the specific issue causing the container startup to fail. (see error below)

**Expected Outcome**:
I expected the Keycloak container to start and run successfully on Cloud Run, listening on port 8080 and being accessible for further configuration and usage.

**Actual Outcome**:
The deployment process fails with an error related to the container not starting and listening on the defined port, despite seemingly correct configurations.

**Docker Compose Configuration**:
To provide more context, here is the Docker Compose configuration I am using:

```
yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
keycloak:
image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
platform: linux/arm64/v8
command: start-dev
environment:
KC_DB: postgres
KC_DB_URL_HOST: postgres_keycloak_demo
KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
ports:
- "8890:8080"
depends_on:
- postgres_keycloak_demo
networks:
- keycloak_demo_dev_network

postgres_keycloak_demo:
image: postgres:latest
platform: linux/arm64/v8
command: ["postgres", "-c", "max_connections=200"]
volumes:
- pgdata_keycloak_demo:/var/lib/postgresql/data
environment:
POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
healthcheck:
test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "keycloak"]
interval: 10s
timeout: 5s
retries: 5
ports:
- "5436:5432"
networks:
- keycloak_demo_dev_network

volumes:
pgdata_keycloak_demo:

networks:
keycloak_demo_dev_network:
driver: bridge
```

Here is the output of my `docker ps` command:

```
| CONTAINER ID | IMAGE                              | COMMAND                | CREATED      | STATUS               | PORTS                              | NAMES                        |
|--------------|------------------------------------|------------------------|--------------|----------------------|------------------------------------|------------------------------|
| 9d9bb4ae9d86 | quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest   | "/opt/keycloak/bin/k…" | 19 hours ago | Up 19 hours          | 8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8890->8080/tcp   | key-keycloak-1               |
| 77481917a5cd | postgres:latest                    | "docker-entrypoint.s…" | 19 hours ago | Up 19 hours (healthy)| 0.0.0.0:5436->5432/tcp             | key-postgres_keycloak_demo-1 |
```

**Annex:**

Here is the JSON content:

```json
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 9,
      "message": "Ready condition status changed to False for Revision keycloak-00001-w8m with message: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=key-api-prod&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/keycloak/revision_name/keycloak-00001-w8m&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22keycloak%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22keycloak-00001-w8m%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start"
    },
    "serviceName": "run.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "v1",
    "resourceName": "namespaces/key-api-prod/revisions/keycloak-00001-w8m",
    "response": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "keycloak-00001-w8m",
        "namespace": "341831814885",
        "selfLink": "/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/341831814885/revisions/keycloak-00001-w8m",
        "uid": "8c36252b-8f91-47f6-a567-107de98402ad",
        "resourceVersion": "AAYSX17OrZk",
        "generation": 1,
        "creationTimestamp": "2024-02-27T16:17:46.228860Z",
        "labels": {
          "serving.knative.dev/route": "keycloak",
          "serving.knative.dev/configuration": "keycloak",
          "serving.knative.dev/configurationGeneration": "1",
          "serving.knative.dev/service": "keycloak",
          "serving.knative.dev/serviceUid": "0f16338f-0676-49db-b6f7-0b8217a12d3a",
          "cloud.googleapis.com/location": "us-central1",
          "run.googleapis.com/startupProbeType": "Default"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "run.googleapis.com/client-name": "cloud-console",
          "serving.knative.dev/creator": "oday.darwich@forty2.ch",
          "autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale": "100",
          "run.googleapis.com/operation-id": "e879ab8e-23e7-417f-a25e-d21373ddab85",
          "run.googleapis.com/startup-cpu-boost": "true"
        },
        "ownerReferences": [
          {
            "kind": "Configuration",
            "name": "keycloak",
            "uid": "cf3b09da-e30d-4fd9-986c-6b3b58219f84",
            "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
            "controller": true,
            "blockOwnerDeletion": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
      "kind": "Revision",
      "spec": {
        "containerConcurrency": 80,
        "timeoutSeconds": 300,
        "serviceAccountName": "341831814885-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "keycloak-1",
            "image": "gcr.io/key-api-prod/keycloak@sha256:fb0fc1584a37eaee6bc862ce51f20c7326986bcc11b90f01733d9e37573f0a28",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "http1",
                "containerPort": 8080
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "1000m",
                "memory": "512Mi"
              }
            },
            "startupProbe": {
              "timeoutSeconds": 240,
              "periodSeconds": 240,
              "failureThreshold": 1,
              "tcpSocket": {
                "port": 8080
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "status": {
        "observedGeneration": 1,
        "conditions": [
          {
            "type": "Ready",
            "status": "False",
            "reason": "HealthCheckContainerError",
            "message": "The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=key-api-prod&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/keycloak/revision_name/keycloak-00001-w8m&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22keycloak%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22keycloak-00001-w8m%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2024-02-27T16:18:02.060185Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "ContainerHealthy",
            "status": "False",
            "reason": "HealthCheckContainerError",
            "message": "The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=key-api-prod&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/keycloak/revision_name/keycloak-00001-w8m&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22keycloak%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22keycloak-00001-w8m%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2024-02-27T16:18:02.060185Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "ContainerReady",
            "status": "True",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2024-02-27T16:17:55.202183Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "ResourcesAvailable",
            "status": "True",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2024-02-27T16:18:01.667535Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "Retry",
            "status": "True",
            "reason": "ImmediateRetry",
            "message": "System will retry after 0:00:00 from lastTransitionTime for attempt 0.",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2024-02-27T16:18:01.667535Z",
            "severity": "Info"
          }
        ],
        "logUrl": "https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=key-api-prod&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/keycloak/revision_name/keycloak-00001-w8m&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22keycloak%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22keycloak-00001-w8m%22",
        "imageDigest": "gcr.io/key-api-prod/keycloak@sha256:fb0fc1584a37eaee6bc862ce51f20c7326986bcc11b90f01733d9e37573f0a28",
        "containerStatuses": [
          {
            "name": "keycloak-1",
            "imageDigest": "gcr.io/key-api-prod/keycloak@sha256:fb0fc1584a37eaee6bc862ce51f20c7326986bcc11b90f01733d9e37573f0a28"
          }
        ]
      },
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.run.v1.Revision"
    }
  },
  "insertId": "-db1h52daq84",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "key-api-prod",
      "service_name": "keycloak",
      "configuration_name": "keycloak",
      "revision_name": "keycloak-00001-w8m",
      "location": "us-central1"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-02-27T16:18:02.076244Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/key-api-prod/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_event",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-02-27T16:18:02.274899828Z"
}
```

Here is the second error

```json
{
  "textPayload": "terminated: Application failed to start: failed to load /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh: exec format error",
  "insertId": "65de0b39000f3051af98d2df",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "revision_name": "keycloak-00001-w8m",
      "service_name": "keycloak",
      "configuration_name": "keycloak",
      "location": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "key-api-prod"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-02-27T16:18:01.995375042Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "instanceId": "00d087f5e0f41e4ed5541a1fa2e1b346e2a50506a851b826e994e75cfda26e0664ee0f8f5630b6709c16eb47e1214003fc8f57462632d76af38dcc7859cfaaf5"
  },
  "logName": "projects/key-api-prod/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fvarlog%2Fsystem",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-02-27T16:18:02.001989221Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run doesn't use Docker Compose so none of the configuration in your Compose file is getting picked up when you deploy to Cloud Run. You either need to specify the config as a knative service yaml (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/yaml/v1#service) or pass it via flags to gcloud run deploy.

Comment: here are the steps i follow
```dockerfile
FROM keycloak/keycloak:latest
ENV KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0"], docker buildx build -t keycloakimage --platform linux/amd64 ., docker tag keycloakimage gcr.io/key-api-prod/keycloakimage, gcloud run deploy keycloak \
  --image gcr.io/key-api-prod/keycloak:latest \
  --platform managed \
  --region us-central1 \
  --allow-unauthenticated \
  --port 8080
```. 
 I still encounter the error:

The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined by the PORT=8080 env. variable.